# And query in Elastic Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch and I'm facing a problem.
I have users index and after adding unique user with username and appId I want to be sure no other user within app can be registered.

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = boolQuery().
                must(termQuery("user", "ara")).
                must(termQuery("appId", "appId"));
```

Java query looks like :

```
SearchResponse existResponse = elClient.prepareSearch("baas").setTypes("users")
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
                .setQuery(query)
                .setSize(1)
                .setExplain(false)
                .execute().actionGet();
```

But resulting hits are of zero length. Response after adding index looks like:

```
{"appId":"appId",
 "updated":1422992226921,"created":1422992226921,"user":"ara",
"password":"9c4a1178d8611f1146b7386e56fbd827",
"salt":"8a669b1562c8c8714fbe9545df719fae"}
```

What's wrong with my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the side effect of using term query. Term query wont apply analyzer on search side , which means it is expecting the exact match of appId and in reality that token would have been lowercase to appid before indexing by default analyzer. 
Mostly the following will work , but then i suggest to move to [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = boolQuery().
                must(termQuery("user", "ara")).
                must(termQuery("appId", "appid"));
```

Comment: It seems so, yes. I've solved the issue but putting mapping and telling it to "not_analyze" those two fields. Worked like a charm. Thanks for the reply, Vineeth.